# How to Count all true and false value in every checkbox

Tags: java, checkbox, count, jframe

:) Sorry for the last question :)

How would I actually count all true and false value of every checkbox and print it
This is the GUI I made..

[image: GUI]

For example, on John's answer's the Items 1,2 and 5 are correct and 3 and 4 are wrong..
I want to print the all correct in the Score textarea and the wrongs are in the Wrongs textarea.. I want to count all the Corrects and wrongs of every people.. and print it

And also Count all the corrects in every items and print it below ..

the True value of the checkbox are corrects and the false value or the unchecked value of the checkbox are wrongs

this is Where i get the logic

[image: logic]

Comment: What is _correct_ and what is _wrong_? According to you example, it is not the _selection_ of the checkbox...

Comment: Noticed you are referencing a previous question and answers.  Could you please edit your post to contain the link to that?

Comment: What have you tried? Please ask a specific questions for a technical problem.

Comment: the True value of the checkbox are corrects and the false value or the unchecked value of the checkbox are wrongs

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the check boxes for a individual in an array or collection.

Iterate over them and count the number of true values.

Comment: How? I tried if else statements for every Persons just for only to count the true and false value... 


`if (chkb1.isSelected){cor1++;}`


`else {wrg1++;}`
that's my logic .. but I think.. It would be many because I will make 50x50 version of that

Comment: So it sounds like you want something like `List<List<JCheckBox>>` to store all 50+ x 50+ checkboxes.  When you create the check boxes put them into a `List<JCheckBox>` for each row, and add the rows into a list.  When you want to score an individual, iterate over that person's list.

Comment: How are you creating the JCheckBoxes? I assume you are using a loop inside a loop?